# Display a js object from the console to the html page

Tags: fetch, display

I'm learning api and request with fetch. I'm a student.
I can't find why when i'm doing like my teacher, everything is going right, but when i have to adapt the code for my personnal working, it doen't work as i' m expecting ; lol...

I want to display on a web page my request result, i can get the array in my console but can't display it on my web page. Could someone help me to find a solution please.
Thank you ! Regards.

```
const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2';
```

async function getUsers() {
const request = await fetch(url, {
method: 'GET',
});

```
if (!request.ok) {
    alert("y'a une couille dans l'beurre!");
} else {
    let datas = await request.json(); // on récupère les données en json et on en fait un objet js;
    /* console.log(datas); */

    document.querySelector('.users').textContent = datas.data[0];
    console.log(datas.data);
}
// on va stocker fetch dans variable : const request;
//await veur dire qu'on va attendre fetch
```

}

getUsers();

Comment: what did get displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the way, you can't just display or inject an entire `object` of data into the `textContent`. `datas.data[0]` is an `object` of data. What you can do instead are:-

###### A. Just pick one data to be displayed

```
document.querySelector('.users').textContent = datas.data[0].email
```

###### B. Just inject entire new HTML

```
document.querySelector('.users').innerHTML = `
 <h2>${datas.data[0].first_name} ${datas.data[0].last_name} (ID: ${datas.data[0].id})</h2>
 <p>${datas.data[0].email}</p>
`
```

###### C. Inject all data available

```
datas?.data?.map((item) => {
  let html = `
    <h2>${item?.first_name} ${item?.last_name} (ID: ${item?.id})</h2>
    <p>${item?.email}</p>
  `;
  document.querySelector(".users").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
});
```

You can see a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-hypatia-n3cpn?file=/src/index.js:484-722